# Convergence of sets on a Hausdorff space (looking for a published reference)

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, hausdorff-distance

I need a reference for the following facts:

- that on $T_1$ spaces, limit and cluster points coincide
- that if $(E,d)$ is a compact metric space, then $(\mathcal{K}(E),d_H)$ is also a compact metric space, where $\mathcal{K}(E)$ is the set of all compact subsets and $d_H$ the Hausdorff metric.

I actually found proofs in a few lecture notes online but I need something published to cite as a reference. Since these are standard, I assume they will be available in most basic books on topology, but I don't have an immediate physical access to many of those. Thanks!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20020623095720/http://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/HAUSF.PDF Theorem 3.3 of this paper shows the second fact

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I actually found that one online, but I did not realize it was a published paper :-)

Comment: cluster point of $A$ = a point such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$? I think this fact is too elementary to be in a paper, I think it is mentioned in Steen and Seebach's counterexamples book. There they call the strong version an $\omega$-accumulation point.

Comment: I found "Hausdorff metric" in the subject-index of General Topology by R. Engelking and was sent to page 298 :Problem 4.5.23  (in  6 parts) which cites 6 references to original publications, which of course are all listed in detail in the Bibliography section of this book. If you ask I will copy them out for you.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes. Maybe I don't actually need a reference for that. I mostly need the other thing and the fact that Hausdorff and Kuratowski metrices coincide on compact metric spaces. I know there is another question here which asks for that exact reference and there is an answer, but if someone had something accessible online (i.e. something I don't have to go to a different library to have a look at) which is also published, that would be great. I should have probably included that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second fact you could use the classic paper by E.Michael [Topologies on spaces of subsets](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042109-4/S0002-9947-1951-0042109-4.pdf), which defines the "finite topology" on the hyperspace (aka the Vietoris topology) and shows that this topology coincides with the uniform topology induced by the Hausdorff metric, and then he shows that for Vietoris we have that the hyperspace of $X$ is compact $T_2$ iff $X$ is. This is where I learnt this from.